# iframe Url search

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I want to make a url search input for an iframe  with HTML (and maybe JS).
I searched in alot of site and I didn't found.

Does anyone know how?

I think I'll need to use something like

```
<form action="http://" method="get" target="myiframe">
 <input id="search" type="text">
</form>
```

?

Comment: So you want a form that when submitted updates an iframe?

Comment: Yeah I can, JS, AJAX and jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
   // Send search form data
   $("#searchFormId").submit(function(event) {
    // stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // get search form input field value
    var s = $('#inpuFieldId').val();
    // update iframe url
    $('#iframeid').attr('src', 'http://example.com?formvalue='+s);
     }
    );
```

Comment: do you need completely script or tips??? you can read docs from jquery for understanding. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: To be honest I need scripts

Comment: I tried  <form action=""  method="get" target="myiframe">
 <input id="search" type="text"><button type="submit" value="go">
</form>

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Update iframe</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body id='body'>
 <div><form action="" method="get" id="myform"> <input id="search" type="text" /><input type="submit" value="go" /> </form></div>
 <div align="center"><iframe name="MyIframe" id="myiframe" src="" width="980" height="500" scrolling="yes"  frameborder="0"></iframe><div>
 <script>
 // Send search form data
   $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    // stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // get search form input field value
    var s = $('#search').val();
    // update iframe url
    $('#myiframe').attr('src', 'http://jquery.com/?s='+s);
     }
    );
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good job trying to help.  Hopefully, this is what they're looking for.

Comment: Easy mistake, I am not the one who asked the question (that was user 2091820)